# apply highest discount

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

Iam working on a Magento project

I have added a single product to many categories.

all those categories have their own discount rates.

for example; Category A - 10%, B - 20%, C - 30%, and D - 40%.

when I add the product to cart which is in all these categories, currently customer get all the discounts. but I want to give only the highest discount rate of all categories the product in that is D - 40%.

How can I do this in Magento?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you want the highest rule to process first you can work with the Priority field of the shopping cart price rules.

Let's say you have rules ranging from 10% to 100%.
All rules with 100% should have priority 0, 90% rules have priority 10, 80% has priority 20 and so on. This will ensure the highest discount has the most priority.

Now on the `Actions` tab set `Stop Further Rules Processing` to **yes** and apply the rule to cart items with the conditions *Category contains [the category ID]*

The `Actions` tab will look something like this:

[image: Actions tab of shopping cart rule]